# Heredoc not printing text in separate lines

Tags: php, string, heredoc

```php
<?php
echo <<<EOT
First
Second
Third
EOT;
?>
```

**Output:** First Second Third

Isn't the output supposed to be like this-

First

Second

Third

?

If not then what is the purpose of `heredoc` and how is it different from a double quoted string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is outputting

```
First
Second
Third
```

But the browser is interpreting this as an HTML document, and by default it wraps lines. Change it to

```
<?php
echo <<<EOT
First
<br>
Second
<br>
Third
EOT;
?>
```

and you'll get the result you expect.

> how is it different from a double quoted string?

Heredocs make it easier to deal with strings that contain nested quotes, because you don't have to escape them. This is especially convenient when creating HTML elements with attributes. Compare:

```
echo "<a href=\"$url\">Some text</a>";
```

with

```
echo <<<EOT
<a href="$url">Some text</a>
EOT;
```

(Yes, I know you can also solve it by putting single quotes around `$url` -- there are many ways to skin the cat.)

Comment: Any alternatives to browser where I can run php scripts so that it is not treated as html document?

Comment: Just run `php scriptname.php` from the CLI, and you'll see the output on your terminal.

Comment: You can also use ideone.com.